# waiting for processes in parallel before running another set of processes with exec

Tags: c, parallel-processing, exec

I have 2 processes that run in parallel, then another 4 processes that run in parallel. I then wait for them to finish before I start another 10 processes to run in parallel, and then wait for those to finish before having the parent finish.

This works sometimes but it sometimes doesnt. Especially at end, the parent exits but the other programs are still running and print stuff after the parent finished already. And it's really repetitive, I tried making it into a function but couldn't get it to work; all processes ran in parallel or only one of each set got executed. Is there a better way to implement this?

```
    ...
waitpid(p1,0,0);
for(i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    switch(p1 = fork()) {
        case 0:
          execl("prog", "prog", NULL);
          exit(0);
        case -1:
          perror("fork");
          exit(1);
    }
}
waitpid(p1,0,0);

for(i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    switch(p1 = fork()) {
        case 0:
          execl("prog", "prog", NULL);
          exit(0);
        case -1:
          perror("fork");
          exit(1);
    }
}
waitpid(p1,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for all the child, but your current code waits for the last child created

try this

```
pid_t p1[10];
int cnt;

/* Replace every instance of your waitpid
 * with this one */
cnt = i;
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
  waitpid(p1[i], 0, 0);
}
```

It doesn't matter which child exit first, the `for loop` with complete only when all the created child had exited.

Comment: @Duck If you put `wait(NULL)` inside the loop the loop will wait for the process to be done before creating the next one, hence they will not execute in parallel.